# Why is $p-1$-th Eisenstein series congruent to 1 modulo $p$ for prime $p \geq 5$?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms

I am reading a paper that references the result
$$E_{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$$
where $p \geq 5$ is prime and $E_{p-1}$ is the Eisenstein series. But the reference references another text, which I have no access to.

Are there any other references to see why this is true? Or, is it obvious enough to post a proof here? Thanks either way.

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by $E_{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$?

Comment: I don't know, actually. I'm assuming that the congruence would be on the coefficients? As in, each coefficient is 1 mod p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Eisenstein series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series#Fourier_series) is
$$E_{p-1}=1-\frac{2(p-1)}{B_{p-1}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sigma_{p-2}(n)q^n$$
where the $B_k$ are Bernoulli numbers and $\sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d^k$.
For prime $p\ge 5$, $p$ divides the denominator of $B_{p-1}$ by the von Staudt-Clausen congruences. So modulo $p$ every coefficient save the initial $1$ is a multiple of $p$ divided by a non-multiple of $p$.